# NameError python subxact

Tags: python, postgresql, triggers, psql

I have the following PSQL trigger, using plpy to execute python functions

```
 -- Function: generatelink()

-- DROP FUNCTION generatelink();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generatelink()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$import io, time
import json
fileName = str(round(time.time()))
with io.open('/opt/maarch/pesv2/event_to_process/'+fileName,'w', encoding='utf-8') as oFile:
    res_id = TD["new"]['res_id']
    plan = plpy.prepare("select * from res_view_letterbox WHERE res_id = $1", ['int'])
    res = plpy.execute(plan, [res_id], 1)
    oFile.write(unicode(json.dumps(res[0], ensure_ascii=False).decode('utf-8')))

    if TD["new"]['status'] == 'FACEXPORT':      
        try:
            plan = plpy.prepare("UPDATE res_letterbox set status = 'FACEXPORT' WHERE res_id = $1", ['int'])
            plpy.execute(plan, [res_id])
        except:
            plpy.notice("Error in UPDATE")
            import sys
            subxact.exit(*sys.exc_info())
            raise
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION generatelink()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

But I have an error when this trigger is executed :

```
Internal error: 7 ERREUR:  NameError: global name 'subxact' is not defined
```

CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):

After few research, I try to use `self.subxact` but I have the same error with `self` instead of `subxact`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sys.exit()`?

Comment: ... or you need to add a transaction in case of you really want to use `subxact.exit()`. `subxact = plpy.subtransaction()`